# How does GPU handle texture and VRAM?

Tags: textures, gpu, memory

It's actually a bunch of inter-related questions:

1. Are compressed textures (dxt5/dxt1 etc.) ever completely decompressed while going through rendering pipeline?
2. If the answer to the first question is true, then how is memory managed for several large uncompressed textures?
3. Is framebuffer any different from VRAM in modern GPU?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

GPU compressed texture formats like [DXT / BC](http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/2012/02/12/understanding-bcn-texture-compression-formats/) / [ETC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ericsson_Texture_Compression) are specifically designed to be read directly from their compressed form. They don't need to be unpacked into a raw RGBA buffer.

The way this works is each block of texels (often 4x4) takes up some fixed number of bits - so we know exactly how far along in the buffer to look for a particular texel - and these blocks can be decompressed without reading all of the surrounding/preceding texture information. GPUs contain specialized hardware that decompresses just the requested texel blocks as needed to fulfill texture sampling requests from your shaders.

This is in contrast to formats like jpg & png, where the amount of space each texel takes up can vary across the image (detailed areas taking up more data, predictable areas taking up less), so to find a particular texel you have to uncompress the whole image, or at least large/distributed chunks of it. But because they can selectively compress predictable areas of a texture, they tend to compress images to smaller sizes for storage on disc or transmission over a network than what we get from GPU-friendly formats. Different strategies for different uses.

---

Generally, asking multiple questions should be done via multiple posts, but since this is a pretty short answer I'll hit point 3 too:

"[Framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer)" is just a particular bit of video memory that we've decided to use to store the composed image we want to present to the screen. Do note the details in JarkkoL's answer, where on some specialized hardware we might choose to locate this buffer in a particular *part* of our available video memory that's optimized for the bandwidth needs of render targets.

Comment: That link on the compression algorithm's is extremely helpful and in-depth. Nice find!

Answer (score 8):

Answers to your questions really depends on the platform. Generally BC formats are kept in compressed form in memory and decompression is done in flight by GPU texture units, but there are exceptions. Namely Xbox 360 is known to decompress complete 4x4 pixel BC blocks to cache before TU fetches the data thus inflating cache usage. I don't know of any platform that would decompress the entire texture to vram upon load though, but I highly doubt it because of the added memory and bandwidth usage.

The same thing goes for framebuffers - it depends on the platform. On Xbox 360 you had 10MB of dedicated high bandwidth EDRAM that you had to use for render targets. On Xbox One you still have 32MB of special ESRAM that is preferred for render targets due to high bandwidth (and can also be fetched from unlike on Xbox 360), but the render targets can also reside in regular DDR3 memory.