# What are the pros and cons of having assets in one file versus multiple files?

Tags: textures

Some games have all their assets in one `.pak` file or something. Or have all their textures in a single atlas. Others have their different assets in different files.

What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: I discuss some of these benefits and complications in an [existing answer here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/146104/39518), if that might be of some help.